# How to mock Http requests with json in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mocking, casperjs, backstop.js

I'm implementing visual tests with BackstopJS and CasperJS in a dynamic application, so I want to mock some http request to have a more stable environment.

I already have mocks to my functional tests using http-backend from Angular but I don't know how to do it on CasperJS. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you already have mocking in Angular.js, what else do you need? CasperJS would just execute the page's code including the mocking.